# Repeat CCAction Certain Number of Times?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, repeat, ccaction

In Cocos2D 2.x, I am doing runAction to do some animations in my game. It is working great but I want the animation to repeat a certain number of times.

So pretty much my pseudo-code is this:

```
CCSequence... action1, action2
[sprite runAction:theSequence];
```

So I just want to repeat the action for (lets say 3 times), how would I do this? I do not see any API to do this but maybe I am just not seeing something. If anyone knows how to do this and could share the information that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *CCRepeat* to repeat an action a number of times:

```
id repeatAction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:theSequence times:3];
[sprite runAction:repeatAction];
```

Comment: How can i increase the speed of repeatforever action ? It says for repeatforever action we can not set speed?? Any help...

Answer (score 0):

### $$ You can use CCRepeatForever to Repeat action: $$

id scaleAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:3.0f scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:2.0];

```
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scaleX:4.8 scaleY:4.8] rate:2.0];

id scaleUpAction1 =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:12 scaleX:4.8 scaleY:4.8] rate:2.0];

CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleAction,scaleUpAction,scaleUpAction1, nil];

[scaleleft runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:scaleSeq]];
```